# Why do some correlation values in pyspark fall outside [-1,1]?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pearson-correlation

I have a dataframe `df_corr` with a single column, each row has a list of prices.

```
+--------------------+
|             prices |
+--------------------+
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
|[101.5,101.0,99.3...|
+--------------------+
```

I want to find the correlation between each pair of columns of prices (eg. correlation between [101.5, 101.5, 101.5, 101.5...] and [101.0, 101.0, 101.0, ...])

For this I am using pyspark's correlation function but I get the values of some of the pairs to be outside the range [-1, 1].
This is my code:

```
pcorr_matrix = Correlation.corr(df_corr, "prices").head()
print(str(pcorr_matrix[0]))
```

The output I get is

```
DenseMatrix([[ 1.        ,  0.        , -0.5       , ...,         nan,
                      nan,  2.12132034],
             [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.5       , ...,         nan,
                      nan, -2.12132034],
             [-0.5       ,  1.5       ,  1.        , ...,         nan,
                      nan,  1.76776695],
             ..., 
             [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  1.        ,
                      nan,         nan],
             [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
               1.        ,         nan],
             [ 2.12132034, -2.12132034,  1.76776695, ...,         nan,
                      nan,  1.        ]])
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

EDIT: The pyspark docs say that the corr function is experimental https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=correlation#pyspark.ml.stat.Correlation.corr

I also calculated by hand and found that some of them should be NaN but aren't - so it looks like there is a bug in the library function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pyspark docs say that the corr function is experimental https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=correlation#pyspark.ml.stat.Correlation.corr

I also calculated by hand and found that some of them should be NaN but aren't - so it looks like there is a bug in the library function.